# All tags are not showing in python

Tags: python

Am parsing on html page using following code

```
request = urllib2.Request(urllink, None, {'User-Agent':'Mosilla/5.0 (\
          Macintosh; Intel\
          Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
          Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'})
urlfile = urllib2.urlopen(request)
page = urlfile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Am generating urllink manually. Here problem is am not getting the entire webpage from,

```
page = urlfile.read()
```

I can see many html contents if i saved the page using "save page as option". Later i got to know that webpage was internally sending many requests. How can i get entire page or can i get those request url's??

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your request a url, it return the sourcecode of the of that page. And maybe the page contains img, css, js files(we call these static files). And your brower will render the html,  it will according the url of those static files to request the resources. Such as `<img src="/static/a.png" />`, then the browser will request the `/static/a.png` to get the img. As same as css and js file.

What's more, now most of the websites are web2.0, which means that we can use ajax to requests resource asynchronously. e.g. `$.ajax({url:'/xxx' ...})`(jquery). And the js may also modify the dom tree, such as adding a new tag.

So if you want to get the all conttents as browser do. You need parse the html or rewrite the ajax requests accoding the javascript to do that. Or if you have a browser kernel, such as webkit, you can alse do the same things as browser. Such as [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/),  [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)
[capserjs](http://casperjs.org/), [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: Ghost.py has some pretty poor support. Do you have any alternatives?